# Get rid of stubborn browser start page

Tags: firefox, about-config

Recently, my Firefox home page became stuck on trustedweb.com (probably as a result of something my son had installed). No matter what I set the home page to, it always goes to that trustedweb.com site. Short of resetting everything, how do I get rid of that stubborn start page?

This is not like the other question that others think that this duplicates. Something has hijacked my browser and is showing its own start page regardless of what I set the start page to (about:blank, superuser.com google.com or whatever). In addition, I get a banner ad at the top of the page of nearly every site that I go to.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Comment: [How to remove “Trusted Web” Ads (Virus Removal Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/trusted-web-removal/) and skip step 2 - just set your home page as you would do normally. And uninstall the anti-malware programs used in the process afterwards.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the link. That seems to have got it and a lot more, too.